# flag always returns 0 to another class

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class QueryParser {
    QueryParameter queryParameter = new QueryParameter();
    public static int flag = 0;

    public QueryParameter parseQuery(String queryString) {
        queryParameter.setGroupByFields(getGroupByFields(queryString));

        queryParameter.setAggregateFunctions(getAggregateFunctions(queryString));

        return queryParameter;
    }

    private List<AggregateFunction> getAggregateFunctions(String queryString) {
        List<AggregateFunction> aggregateFunctionList = null;
        AggregateFunction aggregateFunction;
        if (queryString.contains("count") || queryString.contains("sum") || queryString.contains("min")
                || queryString.contains("max") || queryString.contains("avg")) {
            flag = flag + 1;
        }
        return aggregateFunctionList;
    }

    private List<String> getGroupByFields(String queryString) {
        List<String> groupByFieldList = null;
        if (queryString.contains("group by")) {
            flag = flag+2;
        return groupByFieldList;
    }
}
```

this is my code, now i am accessing flag from another class using
 `int i = queryParser.flag`, 
but it always returns 0. How to declare flag so that it will hold the values from the inner methods and also can be accessed from other classes. /* if anyone need more details please ask i'll add more details, and what more should i write,my main doubt is only to know how i can utilise my flag in another class, thank you for being patient*/

Comment: Welcome to SO. TL;DR; Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) : "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague and have to sum up your entire question in one sentence". Post the shortest code to demonstrate the problem. See: [mcve].  Making the mcve will also help you debug and isolate the problem. You may find out that the problem is not in the declaration of `flag` , but with the logic of changing its value.

Comment: hi, can you point out how i can change flag value (FYI: I reduced the code now)

Comment: Reducing the code is good, but it does not make it [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) could look like this:

```
public class QueryParser {

    public static int flag = 0;

    void getAggregateFunctions(String queryString) {

        if (queryString.contains("count") || queryString.contains("sum") || queryString.contains("min")
                || queryString.contains("max") || queryString.contains("avg")) {
            flag = flag + 1;
        }
    }

    void getGroupByFields(String queryString) {

        if (queryString.contains("group by")) {
            flag = flag+2;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        QueryParser q = new QueryParser();
        System.out.println(flag); //prints out 0
        q.getAggregateFunctions("max"); System.out.println(flag); //prints out 1
        q.getAggregateFunctions("aString"); System.out.println(flag); //prints out 1
        q.getAggregateFunctions("avgNumber"); System.out.println(flag); //prints out 2
        q.getGroupByFields("group by"); System.out.println(flag); //prints out 4
    }
}
```

It helps those who want to help you, and far more important: it is a great debugging tool. 
Making on helps you isolate the problem, and focus on it. 
Like in this case: you can see that the problem is not in the declaration of flag, nor changing its value, but maybe with the input values.

Comment: Hey! thanks mate, i'll follow that from next time to ask a question...good example

Comment: The code is giving out flag correctly in same class. Suppose i call this class(queryParser) from another class, using int i = queryParser.flag; then it is showing flag as 0.

Comment: You can get its value by `QueryParser.flag` or better make it non-static and add a getter.